# Jsp Dynamic Web - Cant see img and css

Tags: jsp

I have Dynamic Web Project in eclipse.
i addded jsp file to it.
in the html i tried to reference to css file

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

but its not working so i out the css in `<style></style>` in `<head>`.
but still i cant get access to images.
i tried in the css background-image and in img tag on html.

```
background-image: url(../images/top-rept.jpg);

<img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" height="101"
 width="157">
```

Comment: where is the css file stored in your project? is it in a sub-folder within the WebContent parent folder?

Comment: I'd also recommend having a separate folder for css files and another folder for images